# How to Fade in each post at a time using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a testimonial section. The testimonials are created via custom post type and are called using foreach loop. Now all the posts are being displayed in the testimonial section.

How can I display a single post at a time with a fade in effect or rather a slide in EF for the following posts.

This is my testimonial section page:

```
<div class="sup_testimonial_section sup_testimonial_section2 sup_toppadder100 sup_bottompadder100">
        <div class="sup_overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <div class="sup_testimonial_heading">
                        <h3>What Our Client Say</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <?php foreach ( $testimonialsposts as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); 
                 ?>
                 <div class="fade-one">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <div class="sup_testimonial_detail">
                        <p><?=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'content', true);?></p>
                        <span><?=$post->post_title?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use [css animations][1].  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: isnt there a way using javascript or jquey ??

Answer (score 0):

Theres a super simple way to do this with classes on divs and data attributes. I did this on michigan.gov/mipage with a jquery plugin called Wow js - > https://wowjs.uk/.
Theres a way to set delay and you can tier that up or down # of seconds as you loop through so each one fades in...Also can set it not to trigger till they scroll...

that url may not have animations for long as that page is slated for getting updated in next month or so.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jQuery you could do this type of thing. This assumes that `.fade-one` display is `none`. You can give it a try:

```
<?php
foreach( $testimonialsposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
    <div class="fade-one">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="sup_testimonial_detail">
                <p><?=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'content', true);?></p>
                <span><?=$post->post_title?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start increment
    var i = 1;
    // Loop through each block
    $.each($('.fade-one'),function(k,v) {
        // multiply increment and fade in
        $(v).delay(500*i).fadeIn();
        // Increment
        i++;
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kjzve8m1/